# Helm v3.7 How to specify repository name of chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3, container-registry

i just upgraded helm to the latest version. We were still running on a version before the breaking changes of 3.7.

So far we have pushed a chart (in Azure Pipeline) into the repo (ACR) as follows:

```
 - script: |
      helm chart save Chart $(ACR_NAME).azurecr.io/helm/storage-api:$(BUILD_VERSION)
    displayName: save new chart 

  - script: |
      helm chart push $(ACR_NAME).azurecr.io/helm/storage-api:$(BUILD_VERSION)
    displayName: push new chart
```

in this example we call the repo `storage-api`. But in our `chart.yaml` the chart name is specified like this: `name: storage-chart`

Since the documentation is not so deep for the new version i dont find an option to specify the name, if i append the name like before a new subfolder will be created in the ACR.

so now we push them like this:

```
- script: |
      helm package Chart --app-version $(BUILD_VERSION) --version $(BUILD_VERSION)
    displayName: save new chart version

  - script: |
      helm push storage-chart-$(BUILD_VERSION).tgz oci://$(ACR_NAME).azurecr.io/helm/
    displayName: push new chart version
```

`helm package ...` creates a .tgz with the name specified in `Chart.yaml`
this has the consequence, that our repo for this service has a new name, the one which is specified in the Chart.yaml. So now its `storage-chart` instead of `storage-api`

Since we have an public ACR changing the names is no option.

Is there a way to specify the repo name in the helm command? Or do I have to change the name in `Chart.yaml``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is no longer possible to determine the repository name.

As of v3.7, this is always derived from the chart name in `chart.yaml`.

[see here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/10169#issuecomment-925377231)